# Sphero robot don't move when I publish in cmd_vel topic

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I try to make a project using sphero robot simulation(gazebo) from this source: [Sphero-ROS](https://github.com/eborghi10/Sphero-ROS).

I run the command: `roslaunch sphero_gazebo main.launch` to start gazebo.

After that I tried to move the robot by keyboard, running the next command in other terminal: `roslaunch sphero_gazebo  keyboard_teleop.launch`. But when I pres the control keys, the robot do not respond.

I tried also to move the robot by terminal running:

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist "linear:
  x: 1.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 10.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0"
```

But did't work. I do not receive any error in console. How can I solve this?

I am using ROS Kinetic.

### edit:

I tried to `echo` the `/cmd_vel` topic in one terminal and in the second one I published using the command above and everything looks like working but the robot don't move.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334699/sphero-robot-don%27t-move-when-i-publish-in-cmd_vel-topic/) by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within your `main.launch` there is the argument `pause` defined like this :

```
  <arg name="pause" default="true"/>
```

That means that you are launching Gazebo in mode pause. You can either modify this in the launch file or launch it with specifying the argument `pause` in command line :

```
roslaunch sphero_gazebo main.launch pause:=false
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-10-07**:
(face palm)

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-10-07**:
thank you :)))